# Prove that, $T/S^1_a\simeq S^2\vee S^1$ where $T$ be the torus which is a CW complex with $1$-skeleton $S^1\vee S^1$ (denoted by $a,b$ respectively)

Tags: algebraic-topology, quotient-spaces, cw-complexes

$T$ is a torus which is CW complex with one $0$- cell $v$, two $1$-cell $a,b$ and one $2$-cell $e_2$.

[image: Torus]

Here in the picture of torus, if we identify the circle $a$, **intuitively** it will look line $S^2/\{p,q\}$
for any two distinct points in $S^2$. Then by using a well know result regarding HEP and homotopy invariance (which says if $(X,A)$ has HEP and $A$ is contractible then $X/A\simeq X$) we can deduce that $S^2/\{p,q\}\simeq S^2\vee S^1$. (Here $\simeq$ denotes homotopy equivalent)

But I am unable to write down a proof of $T/S^1_a\simeq S^2/\{p,q\}$. Can anyone help me in this regard? Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: There's a CW-structure on $S^2$ with two $0$-cells, one $1$-cell and one $2$-cell that is compatible with the given situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to show that $T/\mathbb{S}^1_a$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^2/\{p,q\}$. Define $C=\mathbb{S}^1 \times [0,1]$, if $\mathbb{S^1}_j=\mathbb{S}^1\times\{j\}$ for $j=0,1$, and $\sim$ denotes the relation that identifies $\mathbb{S}^1_0$ and $\mathbb{S}^1_1$ with points we have that:
$$\mathbb{S}^2 \cong C/{\sim},$$

with $p=\mathbb{S}^1_0/{\sim}$ and $q=\mathbb{S}^1_1/{\sim}$. One way to see this is using the [homogeneity lemma](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1701791/homogeneity-lemma-in-point-set-topology) and the fact that the [annulus is homemorphic to the cylinder](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2614004/homeomorphism-between-ring-annulus-and-cylinder). Furthermore, if $\pi:C \to C/{\sim}$ denotes the canonical projection we have that:
$$ \mathbb{S}^2/\{p,q\}=(C/{\sim})/\pi(\mathbb{S}^1_0) \sqcup  \pi(\mathbb{S}^1_1) $$

Now let's write down the homeomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{S}^2/\{p,q\} \to T/\mathbb{S}^1_a$. Define $\tilde{\pi}: (C/{\sim}) \to \mathbb{S}^2/\{p,q\}$ as the canonical projection and notice that we have a map:
$$C\rightarrow^{\pi}\ C/{\sim} \rightarrow^{\tilde{\pi}} \mathbb{S}^2/\{p,q\}.$$
It's easy to see that this map descends to:

$$\phi: C/{\mathbb{S}^1_0 \sqcup \mathbb{S}^1_1} \to \mathbb{S}^2/\{p,q\}.$$

On the other hand:

$$T/\mathbb{S}^1_a = C/{\mathbb{S}^1_0 \sqcup \mathbb{S}^1_1}.$$

So indeed $\phi$ is well defined on the spaces that we need. Finally to see that $\phi $ is a homeomorphism we use the same argument as above to construct a map $\psi:T/\mathbb{S}^1_a \to \mathbb{S}^2/\{p,q\}$ that will be a inverse to $\phi$.